# Linked MySQL Table no longer working in Microsoft SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, msdasql

I have a Microsoft SQL Server that we linked a MySQL DB to a few months ago, it had been working properly, but in the last two weeks we have not been able to access the table as before.

We started receiving the following error in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016:

[image: error received]

I have updated the MySQL ODBC driver to the current version (5.3.9 as of Sept 2017) - recreated the linked table and still receive the same error.

Here are my settings on the Linked DB:

**On the provider Options I have the following boxes checked
- Nested Queries
- Level Zero Only
- Allow Inprocess**

The rest are not checked

The ODBC Connection is set up - it worked before, and when you test the connection it returns a successful connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the connection and started getting another error, similar to this one, but it was referring to the credentials not being correct.  I went into the security tab on the linked table and added our windows service account, and then had it present as the user connecting to the MySQL table and the connection is now working properly.  I also found that on the set up I put in MSDASQL as the data source.

I am not sure what I did to correct the issue, but it is now working and the end users can run queries against the linked table now.